# What's the meaning of #define without replacement in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I encountered some codes as the following:

```
#define MY_IDENTIFIER
void someCode() 
{
    ...
    MY_IDENTIFIER
    ...
}
```

What's the upper code doing ?

Comment: -1 not the real code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I clicked on your name because I though it was a link to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely nothing. The pre-processor is simply replacing `MY_IDENTIFIER` with nothing wherever it encounters it.

Comment: Actually, the preprocessor is. But the result is of course the same.